# Notepad++ how to add a fixed number to different numbers in mysql database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, notepad++

I have a mysql database with over 1500 "x" and "y" map coordinates like 2744,6822 and 3252,7030.

I would like to add a fixed amount of 3000 to each "x" coordinate and 6000 to each "y" coordinate.

Is it possible to do this with Notepad++ or with phpmyadmin?

Thanks

Comment: Should be possible with SQL directly.

Comment: Keep in mind that Notepad is just a Text Editor, nothing else, and PHPMyAdmin a UI to use MySQL in a friendly way.
If you want to add a fixed number, you can do that in your code (since you're using PHPMyAdmin, I assume that it's PHP) on insert or update time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way to do it with mysql query.This will update your whole column by adding 1500 to each element in your column named x and 3000 to column named y.

```
UPDATE table_name SET x = x + 1500;
UPDATE table_name SET x = 1500 WHERE x IS NULL;

UPDATE table_name SET y = y + 3000;
UPDATE table_name SET y = 3000 WHERE y IS NULL;
```